# Connecting to Meteor DDP standalone in browser?

Tags: javascript, meteor, ddp

Is it possible to subscribe to data from Meteor via DDP in a browser stand-alone?

I found the Meteor [DDP package](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/ddp) which states this could be done.

How to use it in a browser stand-alone to receive e.g. collection updates?

Or do you know about other working DDP clients for the browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example there is https://github.com/mondora/ddp.js/, a working isomorphic (browser & Node.js) DDP client library (*I'm not an author of this library and there are a few other available with similar functionality*).

You can easily connect to any DDP server and listen to events. There are examples and API documentation in Readme file. Also look at the tests.

**Example usage:**

Server code:

```
Meteor.publish("myPublication", (param_0, param_1, param_2) {
    /* ... */
});
```

Client code:

```
const subscriptionId = ddp.sub("myPublication", [param_0, param_1, param_2]);
```

Answer (score 3):

I recommend Asteroid, a client-side package for Meteor's DDP: https://github.com/mondora/asteroid

Example usage:

```
   import {createClass} from "asteroid";


   const Asteroid = createClass();
   // Connect to a Meteor backend
   const asteroid = new Asteroid({
    endpoint: "ws://localhost:3000/ websocket"
    });

   // Use real-time collections
   asteroid.subscribe("tasksPublication");

    asteroid.ddp.on("added", ({collection, id, fields}) => {
    console.log(`Element added to     collection ${collection}`);
    console.log(id);
    console.log(fields);
    });

    // Login
    asteroid.loginWithPassword({username, email, password});

    // Call method and use promises
   asteroid.call("newUser")
    .then(result => {
        console.log("Success");
        console.log(result);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log("Error");
        console.error(error);
    });
```